# Why _stomp__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.default.send is not a function?

Tags: typescript, next.js, websocket, stomp

Sorry, I am not familiar with English.
I am implementing the chat function using next.js, typescript, websocket, and stomp.

The notification function is also using websocket and stomp, and it has been confirmed that it is working properly. But it doesn't work properly with the chat function.

```
//stomp.js
import * as StompJS from "@stomp/stompjs";

let token;

if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  token = localStorage.getItem("authorization");

  const webSocket = new WebSocket("wss://~");
  webSocket.onopen = function () {
    console.log("Connection");
  };
}

const client = new StompJS.Client({
  brokerURL: "wss://~",
  beforeConnect: () => {
    console.log("beforeConnect");
  },
  connectHeaders: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  },
  debug(str) {
    console.log(`str`, str);
  },
  reconnectDelay: 15000,
  heartbeatIncoming: 4000,
  heartbeatOutgoing: 4000,
});

export default client;
```

The code below is how you are subscribed on the notification page.

```
export default function StompAlarmSubscibe() {
  if (isLogin) {
   client.onConnect = () => {
    client.subscribe("/message", message => {
      const datas = JSON.parse(message.body);
      console.log("message", datas);
    });
    client.subscribe(`/alarm/${userId}`, message => {
        if (alarms && datas) {
          ... ...
    };
    
    client.onStompError = frame => {
      console.log(`========> Broker reported error`, frame.headers.message);
      console.log(`========> Additional details:${frame.body}`);
    };
    
    client.activate();

}
```

I tried to subscribe from the chat page in the same way as the notification page, but the subscription is not working properly, and send() is not a function.

```
//chatRoom.tsx

const chatRoomSubscibe = () => {
client.onConnect = () => {
console.log("STOMP Connection");

    client.subscribe(`/chat/${chatRoomList?.chatRoomId}`, message => {
        const datas = JSON.parse(message.body);
      });
    };
    client.onStompError = frame => {
      console.log(`========> Broker reported error`, frame.headers.message);
      console.log(`========> Additional details:${frame.body}`);
    };
    
    client.activate();

};

const sendMessage = () => {
const chatMessage = {
senderName: userData.username,
message: userData.message,
status: "MESSAGE",
};

    client.send( //<< error!
      `/pub/chat/${chatRoomList?.chatRoomId}`,
      {},
      JSON.stringify(chatMessage),
    );

};
```

The error code is as follows.

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: _stomp__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.default.send is not a function
```

I'm making a chat room like Twitter. If you click on the chat room list on the left, you will be asked to subscribe with the room ID of the chat room.

I also tried to subscribe on my parent's page, but it didn't work out as I thought.

message.tsx > chatRoomList.tsx > chatRoom.tsx(chatting room)